# Derivative of matrices product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, normed-spaces

Find the derivative of the following matrix

$
f(X) = a^TXb, $ where $ a,b ∈ R^n $ and X is an n×n matrix.

Please give me some serious hint!

Answer (score 1):

$f$ is linear. So its derivative is...

Comment: Could you explain more how to implement my answer!

Comment: The derivative of a linear map at any point is the linear map itself. You should prove it. Then the answer is immediate.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider a function written in terms of the [Frobenius inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product)
$$\eqalign{
 f &= A:X \cr
}$$
whose differential and gradient are 
$$\eqalign{
df &= A:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= A \cr
}$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use what mathcounterexamples.net already said. **However if this is not clear to you you should at lest once write it down in all details**
Let $a = [a_1,...,a_n]^T$, $b=[b_1,...,b_n]^T,[X]_{i,j} = x_{i,j}$

Then
$$\begin{eqnarray*}a^T X b &=& [a_1,...,a_n]\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,1}&x_{1,2}&...&x_{1,n}\\x_{2,1}&x_{2,2}&...&x_{2,n}\\...&...&...&...\\x_{n,1}&x_{n,2}&...&x_{n,n}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}b_1\\b_2\\...\\b_n\end{bmatrix} \\ &=& [a_1,...,a_n]\begin{bmatrix}x_{1,1}b_1+x_{1,2}b_2+...+x_{1,n}b_n\\ x_{2,1}b_1+x_{2,2}b_2+...+x_{2,n}b_n\\...\\ x_{n,1}b_1+x_{n,2}b_2 + ... + x_{n,n}b_n\end{bmatrix}\\&=&[a_1,...,a_n]\begin{bmatrix}\sum_{j=1}^n x_{1,j}b_j\\\sum_{j=1}^n x_{2,j}b_j \\ ... \\ \sum_{j=1}^n x_{n,j}b_j\end{bmatrix}\\&=& a_1\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{1,j}b_j\right) + a_2\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{2,j}b_j\right)+...+a_n\left(\sum_{j=1}^n x_{n,j}b_j\right)\end{eqnarray*}$$

Now try to compute the derivative of this w.r.t $x_1$, $x_2$,... (should be very easy in this explicit form...)

Answer (score 0):

$$f(X)=a^T Xb=\mathrm{Tr}(Xba^T)=Tr(ab^TX^T)=Tr(X^Tab^T)=\left<X,ab^T\right>$$
$$\nabla_Xf(X)=ab^T$$